# PHP sum if equal in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

I am using Laravel to get data from my database using this eloquent

```
$results    = Client::whereIn('po', $pos) -> get();
```

And here is my blade code

```
@foreach($results as $result)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $result -> diameter }}</td>
            <td>{{ round(($result -> boxes - $result -> inventory) * $result -> qty * $result -> m_weight * 1.03) }}</td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

What I am trying to do:

The result will return two duplicated columns under each other.

So I want to sum the two columns value of duplicated and print it in only one row with both columns sum.

Kindly check the image it will show everything in a simple fast way

[image]

Comment: Do it in your query,it`s probably a simple GROUP BY with SUM

Comment: @Mihai can you tell me how please? what is the query?

Comment: @Mihai write the query in an answer so that I could mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the sum would be to do it in the view itself.

```
<?php
    $sum_qty = 0;
    $sum_dia = 0;
?>

@foreach($results as $result)
    <?php
      $qty = round(($result -> boxes - $result -> inventory) * $result -> qty * $result -> m_weight * 1.03);
      $sum_qty += $qty;

      $sum_dia += $result->diameter;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $result -> diameter }}</td>
        <td>{{ $qty }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
<tr>
    <td>{{ $sum_dia }}</td>
    <td>{{ $sum_qty }}</td>
</tr>
```

Try and see whether this suits you.

Since, in the question you mention that you need sum of both the columns, I have done the same. Though the image in the question is confusing, as it has `3.02` in the 3rd row first column.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        $sum_diameter=0;
        $sum_qty=0;
    ?>
        @foreach($results as $result)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $result -> diameter }}</td>
            <td>{{ round(($result -> boxes - $result -> inventory) * $result -> qty * $result -> m_weight * 1.03) }}</td>
{{ $sum_diameter+=$result -> diameter}}
{{ $sum_qty+=round(($result -> boxes - $result -> inventory) * $result -> qty * $result -> m_weight * 1.03)}}
        </tr>
        @endforeach
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
         <th><?php echo $sum_diameter;?></th>
         <th><?php echo $sum_qty;?></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

You can try this...